# Angular Firestore How do I retrieve a sub collection document for editing?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a single document from a firestore sub collection:
database/users/uid/animal/docID

I am able to get the docID parsed from another component successfully but I am struggling with retrieving the information to display in html:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../core/auth.service';
import { AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

interface Animal {
 name: string;
 age: number;
 sex: string;
 breed: string;
 colour: string;
 }

 interface animID extends Animal {
   id: string;
 }

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-detail-animal',
  templateUrl: './detail-animal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail-animal.component.css']
})
export class DetailAnimalComponent implements OnInit {

 curUser: any; // This used to maintain the logged in user. 
 animalDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Animal>;
 animalCol: AngularFirestoreCollection<Animal>;
 animalInfo: any;
 petID: Observable<Animal>;

 constructor(
  public auth: AuthService, 
  private afs: AngularFirestore, 
  private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
  private router: Router,
  public route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
  const petID: string = route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
  console.log('AnimId from route: ', petID)
  const user: any = this.afAuth.authState
 }
 private curPetID: string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

 ngOnInit() {
  this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

  if (user) {
    // get the current user    
    this.curUser = user.uid;
    console.log('Animal ID:', this.curPetID )
    console.log('Current User: ', this.curUser);
    // Specify the Collection
    this.animalInfo = this.afs.collection(`users/${this.curUser}/animals/`, 
    ref => ref.where('id', "==", this.curPetID)
        .limit(1))
        .valueChanges()
        .flatMap(result => result)
        console.log('Got Docs:', this.animalInfo);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then in my HTML(only getting it display for now):

```
<strong>Name: {{ (animalInfo | async)?.name }}</strong>
<br>Breed: {{ (animalInfo | async)?.breed }}
<br>Animal System ID: {{ (animalInfo | async)?.id }}
```

When I run the code, in console.log('GotDocs: ', this.animalInfo) returns undefined.

```
Got Docs: 
 Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MergeMapOperator}
 operator:MergeMapOperator {project: ƒ, resultSelector: undefined, concurrent: 
 Infinity}
 source:Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
_isScalar:false
__proto__:
Object
```

I am not sure if having the above code in ngOnInit() is the right way to go about this either.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an easier approach for reading a single document. You already have the ID, so you can point to that specific document inside ngOnInit:

```
const docRef = this.afs.doc(`users/${this.curUser}/animals/${this.curPetID}`)
this.animalInfo = docRef.valueChanges()
```

Ideally, you unwrap this data in the HTML and set a template variable.

```
<div *ngIf="animalInfo | async as animal">

  Hello {{ animal.name }}

</div>
```

Or you can subscribe to it in the component TypeScript.

```
animalInfo.subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I went back through your book and achieved what I was after with only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

animalInfo is observable type.

Angular2+ supports '| async' pipeline to show observable type directly.
So, if you want to get real data value, you should use subscribe like this:

```
const collection$: Observable<Item> = collection.valueChanges()
collection$.subscribe(data => console.log(data) )
```

I hope this would be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks Jihoon Kwon, that helped heaps. I can see the correct data in console.log() but not in html. I've tried this.animalInfo = collection$.subscribe, then {{ animalInfo.name }} in html and other variations too. Not getting any errors just not displaying the data on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Like @JeffD23 said:

you want to do the "(animalInfo | async) as animal" in an ngIf (recommended solution)

then you do not need the async pipe anymore in your html, do remember to use the new name in the brackets {{}}. if you forgot the names that you gave to your object just use the {{ animal | json }} this will show the Object as json text.

```
const ref = 'location in db';
const animalInfo$: Observable<Item>;
constructor(private service: Firestore) {
  this.animalInfo$ = this.service.doc(ref).valueChanges();
}
```

or you could do the async part in the constructor()/onInit() (backup solution)

```
const ref = 'location in db';
const animalInfo: Item;
constructor(private service: Firestore) {
  this.service.doc(ref).subscribe(item => {
    this.animalInfo = item;
    console.log(item);
  );
}
```

then you can do this again in your html
    {{ animalInfo | json }}

Comment: Thanks Robert. I was missing the the animalInfo in ngIf. Too much reading not enough looking I think ;)